# What is the best datatype to store date in C, to then output into a csv file?

Tags: c, date, csv

I am wondering which data type is most appropriate to store a date? I am reading variables from the command line through argv:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc!=19) {
        usage();
        exit(1);
    }
        int id = atoi(argv[1]);
        int date = atoi(argv[2]);
}
```

Am I right in assuming that I can store it as an int? or is char better? even keep it as a string? I'm not sure on the best practice for this.

Comment: Have a look at `time_t`

Comment: What kind of input are you taking is what you need to consider? It really depends on the format of that.

Comment: so I am inputting a date i.e. "2003-06-16" from a csv file

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want to do with the date. What's your use-case? What are you going to do with the date? Just store (and possibly print) it? Compare it to other dates? Is it important to save space and fit the date in as few bits as possible? Is speed more important?

Comment: @Joachim I only need to print it to put back into a .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse the input into elements of a `struct tm`, then convert into `time_t`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char input[] = "2003-06-16";

struct tm temp = {0};
temp.tm_mday = strtol(input + 8, NULL, 10); // needs error checking
temp.tm_mon = strtol(input + 5, NULL, 10) - 1; // needs error checking
temp.tm_year = strtol(input, NULL, 10) - 1900; // needs error checking

time_t unix_seconds = mktime(&temp);
```

---

Apparently you just need a temporary holding space for the date. So keep it in the same format as input and output: **keep it as a string**.

Comment: how do I to this without having to hardcode the date? I will be passing thouasands of lines into the program....

Comment: Instead of `input + 5` use `argv[12]` for example.

Comment: ahh i see. i will check

Comment: ahh that's instresting about keeping it as a string, i think i want to take this approach. do I just store like  `char date = argv[2]` ? and then `%c` to print it?

Comment: On second thought do not do anything. The input date, in string form, is already saved for you in the `argv` array. Just re-use it (eg `printf("%s", argv[12]);`) when needed. If you need to pass it around and don't want to pass `argv` itself you need to `strcpy()` to a temporary variable: `char tmpyear[5]; if (strlen(argv[12]) < 5) strcpy(tmpyear, argv[12]);`

Answer (score 3):

[The C documentation about date](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono) indicates that you can use the `time_t` type which expresses a date with the number of seconds elapsed since a specific date called Epoch.

Where Epoch is : `00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC`

If I wished to use date without using this time_t lib, I would use long integer.

Answer (score 1):

With [`strptime()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), you get the possibility to parse a date/time string neatly. As this gives you the data in the form of a `struct tm`, you might want to use this.

Comment: +1 but note that [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html) is not described by the C Standard (it is described by POSIX though).